# Django - possible leak of file descriptors?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, multiprocessing, lsof

I am developing application in Django where I want to use multiprocessing in order to perform effective computation but somehow python/Django keeps open file descriptors to local database what makes errors after while.

In file *models.py* I've got class:

```
class VM(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

In second file I've got:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from myapp.models import VM

def multi(vm): 
    summary = vm.summary
    state = summary.runtime.powerState
    vm_name = summary.config.name
    p=VM(name=vm_name, status = state)
    p.save()
```

Method save() is built-in Django.models method for inserting rows in db and I think that it opens file descriptors to db.

```
def my_function():
    x=0
    while(x<100):
        pool = ThreadPool(3)
        pool.map(multi, vms)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        x=x+1
        sleep(1)`
```

Basically *my_function* refresh status of Vms and update it in database.
My problem is that even after closing pool there are open file descriptors to db.sqlite3 and after 20 minutes I've got I/O exception because there are more than 1000 open descriptors to one file. I don't know why Django or python doesn't close it. This is what lsof command returns:

> [root@PC ~]# lsof | grep db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root    6u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root    7u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root    8u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root    9u      REG              253,0     2576    1581352 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3-journal
>
> python     6924      root   10u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root   11u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root   12r      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root   14u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root   16u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root   17u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root   18u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root   19u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3
>
> python     6924      root   20u      REG              253,0  1143808    1581361 /opt/projects/mail/mvp/db.sqlite3`

And longer the app works , more descriptors are opened. Is there any solution for that? Is there any way to close this descriptors and clean after pool workers?

Comment: synchronously spawning threads off a web request that is handled asynchronously is not a good idea. Your problem demonstrated that. In general you give computation tasks to a separate worker, there are systems like celery for this.

Comment: Ok, I found a workaround to that. I created a class my_vm and pasted there everything that is in my_function. Also imported `from django.db import connection` and before creating object of vm_class class I inserted line: `connection.close()` . Now I have max 3 descriptors.